# list contents with batch

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I need a bat file that will list the entire contents of a folder Including its subfolders in a text file.

one of our programs seams to constantly be missing or adding files. a list would help me trackdown the issue(s).

Comment: Your question is supposed to be asked on superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it?

dir C:\autocad /s /b > output.txt

Comment: yes my mistake (change of mind) i would like to run the bat from desktop to check the file contents of C:\AutoCAD

Comment: So, create a batch file with the 'dir' line in it and have it on your desktop?  Or are you actually looking for something that's going to diff the file for you after each run?

Comment: no autocad is acting up and symptoms suggest a missing customisable file some of our systems work though so i want to match information to see thanks for all your help

Comment: you may want to add '\ahs' to the dir command, to make sure it includes hidden/system files as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PowerShell, you can use this instead:

```
cd *<targetdirectory>*
ls -r |% { $_.FullName } | Set-Content foldercontents.txt
```

I only bring it up, because you can then compare the next time you check to see differences:

```
$original = Get-Content foldercontents.txt;
$now = ls -r |% { $_.FullName }
Write-Host "Missing Files:";
$original |? { -not $($now -contains $_) };
Write-Host "Added Files:";
$now |? { -not $($original -contains $_) };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just tracking down what is the program that is creating and removing files, you may monitor all the file accesses in the system with *Sysinternals Process Monitor* http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 . An easy way to watch all the file accesses being done by any process.